# How do I solve logarithmic expressions that have different bases

Tags: logarithms

My math teacher asked me to simplify the following expression to a single logarithm and then evaluate. 
$$\log_{5}125 + \log_{25}5 - 3\log(4)$$ 
 
The bases are different and I found it quite hard to express them as a single log. On my working out I changed the base of $$\log_{25}5$$ to $$\log_{5}25$$ 
$$\log_{5}125 + \log_{5}25 - \log4^3$$ $$\log_{5}(125×25)-\log64$$ $$\log_{5}(3125)-\log64$$ 
 That's all I could simplify it to.

Comment: Is the second one meant to be base $25$? What is the base of the third?

Comment: If you mean $\log_{25}5$ type it like this: \log_{25}5

Comment: I made the corrections.

Comment: Which base is the third one?

Comment: The third one is just base 10

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly changed the base.

A useful logarithm rule is the 'change of base rule'. It states:

$$\log_ab=\frac{\log_na}{\log_nb}$$

This lets you change any base to any other base as the $n$ only appears on the right hand side.

In questions like the one you teacher has given simplification can occur when you have a base which is a rational power of another base. In your problem we see that $25$ is a power of $5$ so we can simplify the second terms as follows:

$$\log_{25}{5}=\frac{\log_55}{\log_525}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\log_55^2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\log_55}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}$$

You can then add it to the first term which you should be able to simplify to 3 by basic definitions.

So this would give you an answer of $$3+\frac{1}{2}-\log_{10}64$$

Additional:

Your textbook asked for it as a single logarithm. This is doable but won't look pretty so I'm questioning if that is actually what the book meant.

$$3+\frac{1}{2}-\log_{10}64=\frac{7}{2}-\log_{10}64$$

$$=\frac{7}{2}\log_{10}{10}-\frac{2}{2}\log_{10}64$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(7\log_{10}10-2\log_{10}64\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_{10}10^7-\log_{10}64^2\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_{10}\frac{10^7}{4096}\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\log_{10}\frac{78125}{32}\right)$$

$$=\log_{10}\sqrt{\frac{78125}{32}}$$

Comment: Sir I tried evaluating your answer, it is not same as the answer of the problem.

Comment: I accidentally put a plus instead of a minus in front of the $\log_{10}64$. I'll update